# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Help needed!
I am struggling setting the cache policy on my wordpress website.
I have tried to set the expirations manually in .htaccess and I have tried several plugins.
Nevertheless Google Page Speed Insights keeps displaying the message "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy".

Is it possible to sort of manually add a cache policy (e.g. via .htaccess) for a specific line in Google Page Speed Insights?

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: PageSpeed Insights suggests to serve static assets with an efficient cache policy, even when you have them set to 31 days (I have that message in my website). Check that you definitely don't have a shorter cache time limit. Also make sure that this message is not caused by external resources that are no under your control.

Comment: @Robert it is probably the case that the cache policy issue is deriving from external resources, as I am beginning to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy".
```

Most likely you are getting this message for resources which are not hosted by your website and is coming from external sites such as Google Analytics code or any other third party code. If that is the case you won't be able to do much and you can simply skip the "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy" suggestion.

If the suggestion is for your own hosted content and you are not able to resolve even after making changes to .htacces files the problem could be in your web hosting and you need to contact them for resolution.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation. 
Suprising that Google penalises it's own cache policy...